# Long lines overlap in Bash PS1 prompt

Tags: bash, unix, ps1

I have configured a **PS1** bash prompt.

My `~/.bashrc` file:

```
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
        PS1='\n\e[0;33m☛ \W\e[0m \n\e[1;35m⤷\e[0m '
fi
```

The problem is that the new line overlaps the previous one.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This seems more appopriate for superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using non-printing characters in a bash prompt, you have to specify non-printing sequences (e.g. color codes) as non-printing, using `\[...\]`:

```
PS1='\n\[\e[0;33m\]☛ \W\[\e[0m\] \n\[\e[1;35m\]⤷\[\e[0m\] '
```