# Using custom colors in zsh PS1 (prompt) env var causes problems with whitespace

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, zsh, macos-catalina

My setup:

- zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)
- macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Here's the standard PS1 var: `PS1="%n@%m %~ %# "`

Problems arise when I try adding text coloring using either ANSI colors or tput. Example (without terminating the color, it behaves oddly regardless of that):

`PS1="%n@%m \e[38;5;197m%~ %# "`

Here's what happens when I use Ctrl+R (reverse search):
[image: weird indents]

What could be the reason for this indent?

Second problem happens when a long string in the prompt goes to the newline - new character after newline overlaps the first line and I can't see the latter. This happens only with the first newline, third one appears normally (but in second place).

I tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306348/long-lines-overlap-in-bash-ps1-prompt) but the solution can't get parsed by the shell: `rombez@MacBook-Pro \[\e[38;5;197m\]~`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ANSI escape sequences don't take up any space on the terminal, so you have to tell `zsh` that they don't contribute to the length of the prompt. You do this by wrapping them in `%{...%}`.

```
PS1="%n@%m %{\e[38;5;197m%}%~ %# "
```

However, you don't need raw ANSI escape sequences in `zsh` nearly as often as you do in `bash`. You can specify a color directly using the `%F` sequence, which `zsh` knows how to handle when calculating the size of your prompt.

```
PS1='%n@%m %F{197}%~ %# '
```